# List to specific dataframe

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I want to create a dataframe from a list. The list is from a shiny handsontable input

When I call the input I got:

```
unlist(input$hot$data)

                                    texta
2                                     80%
3                                    100%
4                                    100%
5                                    100%
6                                   textb
7                                    100%
8                                    100%
9                                    100%
10                                   100%
11                                  textc
12                                    80%
13                                   100%
14                                   100%
15                                   100%
16                                  textd
17                                     5%
18                                    95%
19                                   100%
20                                    35%
```

What I am trying to is to get a df like:

```
col1  col2 col3 col4 col5
texta 80   100  100  100
textb 100  100  100  100
textc 80   100  100  100
textd 5    95   100  35
```

## data

```
# output dput(input$hot$data)
list(list("texta", "80%", "100%", "100%", "100%"), list(
    "textb", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%"), list(
    "textc", "80%", "100%", "100%", "100%"), list("textd", 
    "5%", "95%", "100%", "35%"))
```

Comment: done! see the original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data <- list(list("texta", "80%", "100%", "100%", "100%"), list(
    "textb", "100%", "100%", "100%", "100%"), list(
    "textc", "80%", "100%", "100%", "100%"), list("textd", 
    "5%", "95%", "100%", "35%"))

data <- data.frame(t(sapply(data, unlist)))
```

If don't want `X1`, `X2`, ... as your column names then add:

```
colnames(data) <- paste0("col", 1:ncol(data))
data
```

Then `data` is the following `data.frame`:

```
    col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
 1 texta  80% 100% 100% 100%
 2 textb 100% 100% 100% 100%
 3 textc  80% 100% 100% 100%
 4 textd   5%  95% 100%  35%
```

If you want to remove % symbol and covert your numeric values to numbers then:

```
data[,-1] <- sapply(data[,-1], function(x) as.numeric(sub("%", "", x)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
out <- as.data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(lapply(input$hot$data,  unlist)),
                     nrow = length(input$hot$data[[1]]))))
```

Comment: `unlist` is recursive by default, so `unlist(lapply(input$hot$data,  unlist))` could just be `unlist(input$hot$data)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt.  You could do this all in `matrix()` and wrap in `as.data.frame()`.  No loops are needed (except if you want to convert to numeric - the second part below). Consider `x` to be your given list.

```
## create a data frame from the unlisted values with '%' removed
df <- as.data.frame(
    matrix(
        sub("%", "", unlist(x), fixed = TRUE), 
        length(x),
        byrow = TRUE, 
        dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("col", 1:lengths(x)[[1]]))
    ),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
## convert the character numbers to numeric
df[] <- lapply(df, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
## result
df
   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1 texta   80  100  100  100
2 textb  100  100  100  100
3 textc   80  100  100  100
4 textd    5   95  100   35
```

Comment: I like this `df[] <- lapply(df, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks @EnriquePérezHerrero.  It is certainly a handy function.

Answer (score 1):

Another attempt:

```
d <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(sub("%","",unlist(l)), ncol = 5, byrow = T)), 
          paste0("col", 1:5))

#   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
#1 texta   80  100  100  100
#2 textb  100  100  100  100
#3 textc   80  100  100  100
#4 textd    5   95  100   35
```